# WCF Error 400 (Bad request) when trying to do a POST request in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, wcf, post

I am using AngularJS and I am trying to do REST CRUD operations with ngresources to a WCF service, but every time I try to do a POST call it gives 400 bad request error. I need to send a json object to the service.
This the factory:

```
.factory('oncoNotasService', function ($resource) {

    return $resource("http://localhost:1046/Rest/Onco_notas_enfermeria.svc/oNCO_NOTAS_ENFERMERIAList", {}, {

        query: { method: "GET", isArray: true },
        create: { method: "POST"},
        get: { method: "GET" },
        remove: { method: "DELETE" },
        update: { method: "PUT" }
    });
})
```

And this is the service WCF:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "add")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "oNCO_NOTAS_ENFERMERIAList/", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ONCO_NOTAS_ENFERMERIADto Add(ONCO_NOTAS_ENFERMERIADto oNCO_NOTAS_ENFERMERIADto);
```

I don´t know if I am missing something, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to call the service using a restful client and see if you are getting a 400 response

Comment: Thank´s for the answer. I used an extension of chrome that is a restful client and it helped me to find out that I was sending the field date wrong, after fix this worked fine from the rest client but the angular call keeps failing. I think maybe is a headers issue but I don´t know

Comment: Finally I have been trying many options, and I have found the solution doing the rest petition on Internet Explorer, it seems to be a bowser cross domain issue.

Comment: That makes sense if your angular application is on a different domain from the wcf service

Comment: Yes, it is in a different domain, but how could I make it work? Now I have the same problem with the PUT method even on internet explorer